# Error using Table Alias

Tags: mysql, alias

Why Im getting an error using table alias in the DELETE QUERY but NOT in the SELECT QUERY

This one works fine

```
SELECT * FROM tablename a WHERE a.fieldname > 10
```

This one shows an error message

```
DELETE FROM tablename a WHERE a.fieldname > 10
```

Error message :

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'a WHERE a.field.....

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
DELETE a FROM tablename a WHERE a.fieldname > 10
```

(Of course, aliases are hardly useful in single table statements.)

---

**Answer to second question**

The syntax for multi-table `DELETE` is as follows:

```
DELETE t1
FROM table1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.foo_id=t2.foo_id
WHERE t1.foo1 > 0
```

i.e., you have to tell what table you want to remove rows from (in single table statements it's not required since there's only one table involved).

The syntax is documented at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/delete.html

Comment: Actually I also want to implement the one suggested here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6517664/deleting-records but Im getting an error for this Delete Query

Answer (score 0):

Guess what... you can't use aliases with `DELETE`. Full stop. End of story.

This will work:

```
DELETE FROM tablename WHERE fieldname > 10;
```

Comment: I have seen a lot of response from stackoverflow.com wherein they are using aliases for delete like this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6517664/deleting-records

Comment: @Paul - None of the answers so far in the question you link actually run.

Comment: @Alvaro - Yes but is it really because of alias not really working on DELETE or my host that dont support this alias?

Comment: @Paul, it seems that you have asked this question but you are actually seeking the answer to a different question :(

Answer (score 0):

Hey am getting the same error resolved by little modfication in query.
SO your query should be :

```
DELETE a FROM tablename a WHERE a.fieldname > 10;
```