# Delete with table alias in Mysql

Tags: mysql, innodb

I am try to delete duplicate rows in mysql 5.1 table

query is

```
delete from sessions o where exists (select * from sessions i where i.data=o.data and i.id<>o.id);
```

But it dosent seem to work, I read that using table alias for delete statements in mysql is not possible, but how does this: [Deleting Records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6517664/deleting-records) work?

Comment: "it doesn't seem to work" is not a valid explanation. What is the error message you get?

Comment: @Jocelyn: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'c1 wh
ere exists (select * from sessions i)' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

Try this query -

```
DELETE t1 FROM sessions t1
  JOIN (SELECT data, MIN(id) id FROM sessions GROUP BY data) t2
    ON t1.id <> t2.id AND t1.data = t2.data;
```